How to color the header row of my generated Excel using Angular 17?
I have previously made such module using React.js and Nodejs in which I was fetching data from an array of JSON. Each JSON was then divided into sub excel sheets, color the headers and freeze the panes (1st row and 1st column). By including Node majority of the work was done by my backend. How can I color the header row in frontend only using Angular 17?
I am trying Angular 17 and need to color the header row.
